# Gremlin find all vertices that have "any" property with a given value

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases

The properties in my graph are dynamic. That means, there can be any number of properties on the vertices. This also means that, when I do a search, I will not know what property value to look for. Is it possible in gremlin to query the graph to find all vertices that have any property with a given value.

e.g., with `name` and `desc` as properties. If the incoming search request is 'test', the query would be `g.V().has('name', 'test').or().has('desc', 'test')`. How can I achieve similar functionality when I do not know what properties exist? I need to be able to search on all the properties and check if any of those properties' value is 'test'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the following syntax:

```
g.V().properties().hasValue('test')
```

However, with any size dataset I would expect this to be a very slow traversal to perform as it is the equivalent of asking an RDBMS "Find me any cell in any column in any table where the value equals 'test'".  If this is a high frequency request I would suggest looking at refactoring your graph model or using a database optimized for searches such as Elasticsearch.

Comment: we are considering using elasticsearch as an alternative to this. What is your opinion on concatenating all the keys and values(form a json doc) and store that against a property in the graph, say summary and then query on this property using full-text implementation of the graph? something like `g.V().has('summary', TextP.containing('test'))`. would that perform any better? I am specifically looking at a cosmosDB graph API solution if that makes things any simpler